# The opacity on two h3 tag is different. How can I make it the same

Tags: html, css

```css
.description {
  opacity: 0.5;
  margin: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="description">aaaaaaa</h3>
<h3 class="description">bbbbbbb</h3>
```

I have a code like this and the output looks like this
[image]

How can I make both of the h3 description opacity 0.5?

Comment: show us full code, am sure that the background is different .. the opacity is clearly the same

Comment: Are you using any kind of css framework in your project or the design is completely yours?

Comment: Why would removing the double gap on my jsfiddle work and add the opacity to the first tag: https://jsfiddle.net/m685fL0j/1/. Surely duplicating the second tag and removing the first tag (with aaaaaaa) in, will prove that!?

Comment: With the given code we cannot reproduce the issue. Please post a [SSSCE example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: @fcalderan also called a `[mcve]` here :) [mcve]

Comment: @M.Ferguson well i have nothing to say but simply that HMLT/CSS doesn't work like that ... add as many gap as you want it's always the same

Comment: @HamzaAbdaoui please don't create a snippet with a code that doesn't reproduce the issue, it's useless and make the question irrelevant.

Comment: @TemaniAfif Please do not remove the snippet. It seems to show the issue

Comment: Thank you @TemaniAfif, I've just wanted to show the result of that code, instead of using an image.

Comment: @mplungjan no i doesn't :) it's clearly different from his screenshot, so we don't have to make it a snippet unless we have more CSS

Comment: @TemaniAfif On my Chrome the aaa's are clearly not opacity .5. OP should update the snippet with the blue color

Comment: the reason is a hidden char before the class in the first line

Comment: @mplungjan there is a hidden char added with the update i guess and not related to op issue/ or maybe related

Comment: You guess wrong. the char is in the original question

Comment: As per my answer

Comment: @mplungjan but it brokes the whole code then and the OP should have notice this ...

Comment: @M.Ferguson You talked about a gap which is very different ! you create confustion to everyone saying there is no need to have GAP between h3 and class which is totally wrong. In this case it a special Char and not a gap

Comment: @mplungjan in my case i see both h3 embeded .. the first one is inside the second one and the first one is broken

Comment: In the original question there is a https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm between `<h3　class` If I remove it, the two H3s are identical in opacity. JSFiddle does not even see the first tag: https://jsfiddle.net/nev5kjnr/

Comment: @mplungjan yes i agree with this strange char ;) but my opinion is that if we inspect the dev tool we will clearly see it is a complete mess. there is no `h3` tag with the first word .. the special char create a new type of element which is `<h3 class="descrption"></h3 class="descrption">`

Comment: @mplungjan hope the OP will read all these comments so he understand his issue

Comment: @TemaniAfif That is correct. I see what you mean now. In the fiddle we have exactly that: `<h3　class="description">aaaaaaa
<h3 class="description">bbbbbbb</h3>
  
</h3　class="description">`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9L12as56/

Comment: @M.Ferguson's  answer was correct. It did not show because we did not have the rest of the CSS. Also the question is not unclear

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think you have been a bit of a bully on the question. Removing snippets, voting down M. Ferguson. The GAP is a SPACE character that took quite a bit of research to find.

Comment: @mplungjan it's not my fault ... M Ferguson didn't explain well what he meant, we used wrong words which create confusing to everyone and the snippet wasn't here at the beginning ... and adding the screenshot make it more complicated as we all thought about missing CSS  and he was talking about opacity --> but at least i tried to comment in order to hightlight the issue ;)

Comment: Christ, talk about putting newer users off of helping people

Comment: I'm so sorry. After rewriting the CSS code this problem had disappeared. I think some other CSS code was bothering it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a *Unicode Character 'IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE' (U+3000)* within the first h3 tag:

```
<h3　class="description">aaaaaaa</h3>
```

Between the h3 and the class, remove this and it will work

https://jsfiddle.net/m685fL0j/

If you paste the first H3 into

https://www.url-encode-decode.com

You will see the character:

%3Ch3**%E3%80%80**class%3D%22description%22%3Eaaaaaaa%3C%2Fh3%3E

Comment: that makes no difference

Comment: try to put a space and it still will work

Comment: @fcalderan it was a space-type character - here it is even more clear: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/9L12as56/

Comment: @Bart - you can also revisit this :)